# "Big" groups $G$ with trivial $Out(G)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

We are looking for examples of groups $G$ such that $G$ is "big", but $Out(G)$ is trivial. By "big" we mean things like virtually free, or large, or Golod-Shafarevich. However, we would like our groups to be residually-finite.

**Edit**: Henry, Igor and Lee thank you for all your help. Eventually, we only needed finite $Out(G)$ with $G$ having a trivial center. Thus, $A*B$ was the example we used. It is included in "[Large normal subgroup growth and large characteristic subgroup growth](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07866.pdf)" (sorry for the self-promotion, but I thought people might be interested in our motivation and the results of their help).

Comment: I suspect $\PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has trivial outer automorphism group, though I never worked it out.

Comment: @HJRW What about inverse transpose?

Comment: Good point! I guess I meant finite. In any case, there should be lots of virtually free examples.

Comment: Just to emphasize we mean trivial $Out(G)$ and not finite.

Comment: @HJRW one actually has to be careful, because that automorphism is *inner* in $GL(2, \mathbb{Z}),$ but the conjugation is by a matrix of determinant $-1.$

Comment: @YiftachBarnea -- yes, sorry, I was careless.  But I expect there to be lots of virtually free examples with trivial outer automorphism group. For instance, I expect $S_7*S_8$ to work.

Comment: @HJRW Thanks! Virtually free is much better for us. Why do you think $S_7 * S_8$ has trivial outer automorphism group?

Comment: If $A,B$ are nontrivial, nonisomorphic, finite or one-ended groups then $A*B$ has outer automorphism group of the form $\text{Aut}(A) \times \text{Aut}(B)$: the obvious homomorphism $\text{Aut}(A) \times \text{Aut}(B) \to \text{Aut}(A*B) \to \text{Out}(A*B)$ is an isomorphism (and so it's never trivial).  Levitt wrote down those kinds of formulas in one of his papers. So for example the outer automorphism group of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) \approx \mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/3$ is cyclic of order 2.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks! Great this is the example we needed. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @LeeMosher -- good point.

Comment: @YiftachBarnea -- I'm unclear why Lee's comment answers your question. It implies that the infinite dihedral group is the only free product without non-trivial outer automorphisms. I still suspect some virtually free examples exist, and can think about it some more if it would help.

Comment: @HJRW you are right. It was late and my brain replaced $Aut(A) \times Aut(B)$ by $Out(A) \times Out(B)$. An example of  virtually (non-abelian free) would be much appreciated. Otherwise we will need to look at the specific example and hope it has the property we need and that we can prove it.

Answer (score 13):

There are many, many examples of large, residually finite groups with trivial outer automorphism group. Indeed, any nonabelian virtually special group is large and residually finite. Furthermore, if they're hyperbolic,  Paulin showed that they have finite outer automorphism group unless they split over a virtually cyclic subgroup; in particular, most such examples have trivial outer automorphism group. Instances of this include:

- fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds;
- random groups at density less than 1/6;
- most small-cancellation groups;
- groups constructed using the Rips construction;

etc etc.

Comment: Henry, just to make sure do you mean large in the sense that a subgroup of finite index maps on a non-abelian free group?

Comment: @YiftachBarnea, yes, I mean large in the sense of Pride.

Comment: I think the result you mention about outer automorphism groups of hyperbolic groups should be attributed to Bestvina and Feighn: it is proved in their paper untitled *Stable actions of groups on real trees* (in fact, the first step of the proof is based on a construction due to Paulin).

Comment: @Seirios, you're quite right. It's usually called Paulin's theorem, although it's true that the version of the Rips machine that the argument uses was worked out by Bestvina and Feighn.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that Bumagin-Wise (Every group is the outer automorphism group of a finitely generated group, J. Pure App. Alg. 2007) used a variation on Rips construction to prove that given any finitely presented group $Q$ there exists a finitely generated, residually finite group $Q$ such that $\operatorname{Out}(G_Q)\cong Q$. Here, $G_Q$ is the kernel of Rips construction, so if we take $Q$ to be trivial then $G_Q$ is $C{\prime}(1/6)$ and we get an explicit presentation. If $Q$ is finite then $G_Q$ is still hyperbolic, large, virtually compact special, etc.

Answer (score 9):

A countably-infinite family of groups is given at the end of Section 6 of a paper of A. D. Logan<sup>1</sup>: for each natural number $n>1$, the two-generator-, one-relator group

$$G_n := \langle a, b; (a^{−2}ba^4ba^{−3}ba^5b)^n\rangle$$

has trivial outer automorphism group.

**EDIT** This has nothing to do with the above, but I don't want to add a third answer :) My discussion with Henry in the comments to the OP, might suggest that $Out(PGL(2, \mathbb{Z}))$ might be trivial. Apparently, this was proved by Hua and Reiner in 1951-1952, and then disproved(!) by Joan Dyer in 1978, where she constructed an outer automorphism (known ever since as the Dyer automorphism, so $Out(PGL(2, \mathbb{Z})) = C_2;$ the "so" is not trivial but true.

For completeness, her automorphism $\mathcal{D}$ is described as follows. The generators of $PGL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ are:

$$S = \pm \begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, T=\pm \begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},B=\pm \begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the automorphism sends $S, T, B$ to $SB, TB, B.$

<sup>1</sup><sub>A. D. Logan: *The outer automorphism groups of two-generator, one-relator groups with torsion*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 144 (2016) 4135-4150</sub>

Comment: is this group virtually (non-abelian free)?

Comment: @YiftachBarnea I am suspecting that yes, but can't do better than that at the moment.

Comment: It's not. If it were virtually free, it would be a free product of cyclic groups, and have a non-trivial outer automorphism.

Comment: @HJRW ah, ok (although in the other comment thread you conjecture that a free product of cyclic groups has a trivial outer automorphism group...)

Comment: to suspect is not conjecture, and this "suspicion" was already discarded. And indeed a non-abelian free product of cyclic groups has non-inner automorphisms (if at least one has $\ge 3$ elements, take inversion on it and  identity on others; if all have 2 elements, take a non-trivial permutation of factors).

Comment: @HJRW are you using some result on 1-relators that are virtually free? they're always free products of cyclic groups?

Comment: @YCor It appears to be a long-standing conjecture that every one-relator group of the form $\langle a, b \left| R^n\right. \rangle$ is virtually free by cyclic, so my is not so far off the wisdom of the ancients (in this case, of the late lamented G Baumslag.

Comment: Thanks Igor but this is not my question. I refer to HJRW's claim "if it were virtually free, it would be a free product of cyclic groups"

Comment: @YCor Magnus-Karrass and Solitar says that every one-relator group with torsion is virtually torsion-free. Pride (1977) says that a two generator subgroup of a one relator torsion group is either free or has torsion (actually, closer to Henry's statement, it is a free product of cyclic groups, or a one relator group with torsion). Which tells us that the torsion-free subgroup has the obvious property (that every two generator subgroup thereof has torsion), but since the finite index subgroup I conjecture need not be two-generator, I am not sure what Henry has in mind.

Comment: By the way, @YiftachBarnea , this group IS word-hyperbolic.

Comment: @YCor sorry typo in my long comment "every two generator subgroup of the torsion-free subgroup is free'

Comment: My reasoning was quite simple: the only torsion in a one-relator group comes from powers of the relator; in particular, there is only one conjugacy class of (maximal) finite subgroup, which is cyclic. Therefore, if it is virtually free, it must be a free product of an infinite cyclic group and a finite cyclic group.

Comment: OK thanks (that all torsion elements of 1-relator groups are conjugate to a power of the relator is probably standard but nontrivial; at least it's not a fact I know by heart!). On the other hand, to conclude you need to sort of use Stallings's theorem or at least some easier version thereof. Then there's slightly more than what you claim: you can have a semidirect product $C\rtimes F$ of a cyclic and a free group, which also has this property of having a single maximal finite subgroup up to conjugacy (but I don't know if this can be 1-related).

Comment: @YCor The first statement is Theorem 4.13 in Magnus-Karrass-Solitar.

Comment: @YCor, yes, one also needs to invoke Stallings' theorem to say that every virtually free group is a graph of finite groups. The upshot of all this is that the only 2-generator, one-relator virtually free groups are free products of cyclic groups (one finite).

Comment: @HJRW But you don't tell me why a non-free infinite (finite cyclic)-by-free group can't be a 1-relator group.

Comment: @HJRW Fischer, Karrass and Solitar proved (On one-relator groups having elements of finite order, PAMS 1972) that $G=\langle X; R^n\rangle$, $n>1$, is virtually free if and only if $G$ is the free product of a free group and a finite cyclic group. In fact, they prove that if $G$ has more than one end then it has infinitely many and is a free product of a nontrivial free group and an indecomposable one-relator group (which is decidable). It follows (perhaps not "clearly", but it does follow!) that if $G=\langle X; R\rangle$, $R$ not a proper power, is virtually free then it is free.

Comment: @ADL, thanks for the reference. It was clear to me that this should be true, but I got bogged down in the details of the proof.

Answer (score 7):

All fundamental groups of finite volume hyperbolic manifolds (of dimension $\geq 3$) have finite outer automorphism groups, and most have trivial outer automorphism groups.