# Examples of groups for which Margulis superrigidity theorem applies

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lattices, arithmetic-groups

I am not an expert at all in the subject of Lie groups, lattices, arithmetic groups and rigidity. But, lately I am interested in Margulis superrigidity theorem, which in most versions can be stated as follows:

Theorem. *Let $G$ and $G'$ be semisimple connected real center-free Lie groups without compact factors with $\mathrm{rk}(G)\geq 2$, $\Gamma < G$ be an irreducible lattice, and $\pi: \Gamma \to G'$ a homomorphism with $\pi(\Gamma)$ being Zariski dense in $G'$. Then $\pi$ extends to a rational epimorphism $\pi':G\to G'$.*

Here "$H$ is without compact factors" means, for $H$ center-free, that if we write $H=\prod_{i=1}^kS_i$ with $S_i$ simple, then each $S_i$ is non-compact, or equivalently has positive (real) rank; the (real) rank $\mathrm{rk}(H)$ of $H$ is the sum of the ranks of all $S_i$. Irreducibility of a lattice $\Gamma$ means that its projection in $H/S_i$ has a dense image for all $i$.

Questions:

> Do you have examples of Lie groups and lattices for which Margulis theorem applies, and also groups for which the theorem does not holds.  In particular, do this theorem apply for $G=G'=\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma=\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Does this implies that $\mathrm{Out}(\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{Z}))$ is finite?

Thank you all.

Comment: If $G$ semisimple is written as $S_1\dots S_n$ where $S_i$ are its simple normal subgroups, "no compact (simple) factor" means that none of the $S_i$ is compact. Probably MathStackExchange seems more appropriate.

Comment: For $n\ge 3$, $Out(PSL_n(\mathbf{Z}))$ is finite. More generally $Out(\Gamma)$ is finite for every irreducible. lattice $\Gamma\subset G$, $G$ semisimple not locally isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$. This follows from Mostow rigidity (which is anterior to the stronger Margulis' superrigidity): every automorphism of $\Gamma$ extends to an automorphism $G$. Since $Out(G)$ is finite, a finite index subgroup of $Aut(\Gamma)$ consists of the normalizer $N$ of $\Gamma$ in $G$. Since $N$ contains $\Gamma$ with finite index, $Out(\Gamma)$ finite follows.

Comment: (For $n\ge 2$ $Out(PSL_2(\mathbf{Z}))$ is also finite, as mentioned by Igor, but for reasons essentially unrelated to (super)rigidity: but this does not hold for its torsion-free finite index subgroups)

Comment: @YCor: Why does $N$ contain $\Gamma$ as a finite index subgroup?

Comment: Since $\Gamma$ is Zariski-dense, so is its normalizer. Hence the Lie algebra of its normalizer is an ideal. If by contradiction this ideal is nonzero, $N$ contains a simple factor $S$; since $S\Gamma$ is dense by definition of irreducibility, it follows that $N$ is dense, and being closed, we get $N=G$, contradiction (every discrete normal subgroup of $G$ being central). So $N$ is discrete. Since it contains $\Gamma$, it's a lattice, and the covolume of $\Gamma$ is $[N:\Gamma]$ times the covolume of $N$, and hence the index is finite.

Comment: PS: there are several questions in your question; some but not all rather belong on MathSE. The question why (super)rigidity implies finiteness of Out is reasonable here. Possibly you could reedit accordingly.

Comment: Than you @YCor. This is the kind of arguments that I did not find in the literature, at least in the standard references, althogh I found in some places the statement that "rigidity implies finite Out". Kind of the same happens with the examples of groups for which either Margulis or Mostow theorem applies.

Comment: I edited the question. The initial first question "what does *without compact factors* mean" was not worth a question. I removed the assumption "$\pi(\Gamma)$ is not precompact" because in this setting this is superfluous when $\pi(\Gamma)$ is supposed to be Zariski dense. Still, the main question is unclear: "what are examples of Lie groups and lattices for which Margulis theorem applies" means that you first define what it means for such a triple $(G,\Gamma,G')$ for Margulis theorem to apply, and I expect you don't restrict to hypotheses of the theorem since otherwise the question is empty.

Comment: I have partially related interests in tangential areas that i would love to request references for, but as I'm unable to ask questions  my time may be more wisely spent googling youtube videos.  Let me know how your research in Lie groups goes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way it is stated, the "Theorem" is false. Take $G=PSL_3(\mathbb R)$, $G'=SL_3(\mathbb R)$, and $\Gamma ' \subset G'$ a torsion free lattice. Then the map $G'\rightarrow G$ sends $\Gamma '$ isomorphically to a lattice $\Gamma \subset G$. But the map $\Gamma \simeq  \Gamma '$ does not extend to a rational  epimorphism $PSL_3(\mathbb R) =G \rightarrow G'=SL_3(\mathbb R)$. It is not just that $G,G'$ are center freee but are of adjoint type (over $\mathbb C$, they should be centre free).

(the modified question has been answered by many people in the answers and comments).

Answer (score 0):

Compact factors:

$$SO(3) \times SO(3).$$

No compact factors $SL(3, \mathbb{R}).$

$SL(3, \mathbb{R})$ - theorem applies. $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ -- does not (rank 1). $Out(PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ *is* finite, however - it consists of the Dyer automorphism (which is an involution) and the identity, see my answer to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265055/big-groups-g-with-trivial-outg/265062#265062)

Comment: Than you for your answer. I was tinking on finiteness of $PSL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n\geq 2$, I already edited my question. Do you know if all that outer automorphisms groups are finite? do youknow any good reference?

Comment: It is known that $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(n)\times \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m=n(n-1)/2$. That was actually the reason I got confused in the first place, I mean, it seems like $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ does have a compact factor

Comment: Yes "compact factor" is somewhat ambiguous. It should be "compact simple factor in this case", but this remains ambiguous. I explained the intended meaning in my first comment to your question.

Comment: I see, so, the "word" factor should be understood as group theoretic factors, not as direct factors. I guess the decomposition of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})=SO(n)\times \mathbb{R}$ is not a contradiction siince $\mathbb{R}$ is not considered simple as a Lie group.

Comment: It's not the point. First, $SL_n(\mathbf{R})=SO(n)\times \mathbf{R}$ is senseless since they are not even homeomorphic (different dimension). It's true that $SL_n(\mathbf{R})$ is homeomorphic to $SO(n)\times \mathbf{R}^{n(n+1)2-1}$. But it's not a group isomorphism.

Comment: It's not a general group-theoretic definition, it's specific to semisimple Lie groups. For semisimple Lie group with trivial center anyway, "simple factor" means "simple normal subgroup", "simple direct factor", which are the same in this setting.